# Is there goal line technology in FIFA 15 (PC)?

Tags: pc, fifa-15

I saw on many youtube videos of goal line technology in FIFA 15, but when playing, it never happened (and there were many chances).
Can someone confirm that there is this feature in PC version?
I'm playing in Italian Serie A, maybe this feature is disabled because in Serie A there isn't this technology?

Comment: How would that manifest in the game? You mean if there is a replay where you see if the ball was in or not? Can you link to such a video you are talking about?

Comment: I have played Fifa 15 a lot both on PC and PS4 and never came across such a scene. Either it's tied to a certain gamemode or league or it was cut from the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it is in the PC version. I have seen 2 replays (one of which, the ball wasn't even close to the line) - and I've been playing mostly pro career mode (although I have done a fair bit of manager mode too - but not seen it here) over 150 hours. My player is currently playing in the EPL and that's when the replays occurred.

I think it may be more prevalent, but I usually skip replays (and goal line tech is not an instant review).

Comment: Finally it happened! it was in friendly game. But during career mode(manager) never happens